# iOS - Array not being filled - NSDictionary / NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, plist

I am having issues with XCode and require help pretty quickly... I have a plist file which I need to access and it should be filling the array of all vehicles available... Unfortunately it is not doing this.
rootPath has a value.
path has a value.
`settings` does **NOT** have a value, it comes back as nil. Why is this? As far as I am aware this used to work on older versions of iOS / OS / XCode versions.
Any ideas would be perfect! Here is the code that is going wrong with the plist file:

```
    -(NSArray *)AllAvailableVehicles {
    // load in vehicles from plist data

    //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
    //                  @"vehicles" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                              NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vehicles.plist"];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSArray *array = [settings objectForKey:@"Vehicles"];

    NSMutableArray *vehicleMutArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in array){
        Vehicle *vehicle = [[Vehicle alloc] init];
        vehicle.displayName = [dict objectForKey:@"Display Name"];
        vehicle.keyName = [dict objectForKey:@"Key Name"];
        vehicle.maxPassengers = [[dict objectForKey:@"Max Passengers"] intValue];
        vehicle.cabCode = [dict objectForKey:@"Cabmaster Code"];
        vehicle.luggageImage = [dict objectForKey:@"Image"];
        [vehicleMutArray addObject:vehicle];
        [vehicle release];
    }
    NSArray *vehiclesArray = [[vehicleMutArray copy] autorelease];
    return vehiclesArray;

}
```

plist file:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd" PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN">

-<plist version="1.0">


-<dict>

<key>Vehicles</key>


-<array>


-<dict>

<key>Display Name</key>

<string>Saloon Vehicle - 4 Seats</string>

<key>Key Name</key>

<string>Standard</string>

<key>Max Passengers</key>

<integer>4</integer>

<key>Cabmaster Code</key>

<string> </string>

<key>Image</key>

<string>Standard.png</string>

</dict>


-<dict>

<key>Display Name</key>

<string>Estate Car - 4 Seats</string>

<key>Key Name</key>

<string>Estate</string>

<key>Max Passengers</key>

<integer>4</integer>

<key>Cabmaster Code</key>

<string>E</string>

<key>Image</key>

<string>Estate.png</string>

</dict>


-<dict>

<key>Display Name</key>

<string>VIP - 4 seats</string>

<key>Key Name</key>

<string>VIP</string>

<key>Max Passengers</key>

<integer>4</integer>

<key>Cabmaster Code</key>

<string>V</string>

<key>Image</key>

<string>Exec_Car.png</string>

</dict>


-<dict>

<key>Display Name</key>

<string>MPV - 6 Seater</string>

<key>Key Name</key>

<string>MPV - 6</string>

<key>Max Passengers</key>

<integer>6</integer>

<key>Cabmaster Code</key>

<string>M</string>

<key>Image</key>

<string>6Seater.png</string>

</dict>


-<dict>

<key>Display Name</key>

<string>MPV - 7 Seater</string>

<key>Key Name</key>

<string>MPV - 7</string>

<key>Max Passengers</key>

<integer>7</integer>

<key>Cabmaster Code</key>

<string>N</string>

<key>Image</key>

<string>7Seater.png</string>

</dict>


-<dict>

<key>Display Name</key>

<string>Minibus - 8 seats</string>

<key>Key Name</key>

<string>Minibus</string>

<key>Max Passengers</key>

<integer>8</integer>

<key>Cabmaster Code</key>

<string>O</string>

<key>Image</key>

<string>Mini.png</string>

</dict>

</array>

</dict>

</plist>
```

Comment: So, how are you adding the plist file? Is it bundled with your app or you are writing into doc directory?

Comment: try [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity]

Comment: NSLog path and double check if it is really correct.

Comment: @CalinChitu what change would that make? ´arrayWithCapacity´ should do the job nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, Calin I will try that now...
Aadhira, I add it within my compile sources due to the way the project was set up before I started working on it.

Comment: Here are the values of rootpath and path....


rootpath = 

/Users/cabmaster/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/3658EA14-63F5-482D-9615-6A1663AE74EA/Documents

path = 

/Users/cabmaster/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/3658EA14-63F5-482D-9615-6A1663AE74EA/Documents/vehicles.plist

Comment: Hey, first try to print the file contents as string, by `NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];` just to find, whether it could be problem with dictionary format.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0xd0a3cf0 {NSFilePath=/Users/cabmaster/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/3658EA14-63F5-482D-9615-6A1663AE74EA/Documents/vehicles.plist, NSUnderlyingError=0xd0996a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}

Comment: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vehicles" ofType:@"plist"];

Comment: faizii- this has been answered already below and sadly does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue! It turns out I had some build rules which meant that the Plist Files would not copy over, I removed all of the build rules and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                          NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vehicles.plist"];
```

with

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vehicles" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Comment: When I do this "path" comes back as nil... Let me try doing a clean + build and I will get back to you.

Comment: How have you added vehicles.plist to your project?

Comment: I have, it is both within my compile sources + copy bundle resources. After a clean and build it still has the same error.